# Error while selecting the database items according to the first letter using php and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, prestashop

I want to create a simple program which function is:
The user chooses a letter from a simple form and then the program generates all the elements from my "prestashop" named database which start with this letter.
I created the database in phpmyadmin and created the code in php and in ajax. But I'm not sure if this piece of my code really makes the selection of the elements which start with the letter chosen from the user.An error occurs anyway.[image]
Here is my php code:

```html
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);/* 54-th row*/

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','prestashop');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"prestashop");
$sql="SELECT * FROM prestashop WHERE marca LIKE '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Marca</th>
<th>Descrizione</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {/* 70-th row*/
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['marca'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['descrizione'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Is there something I should change to make this works?

Comment: your mysqli_query is returning `false`. echo your `$sql` and run it directly to the database (through phpmyadmin for example) and see what error it gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of, correct syntax for "like" in mysql is:

```
LIKE '%foo%'
LIKE '%foo'
LIKE 'foo%'
```

Secondly, according to PHP documentation regarding [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So you will need to check what it returns and if it is false, show some error for example.

Comment: Should I do echo"$sql" ?

Comment: @Doe Change your SQL LIKE statement to ... LIKE '".$q."%' and perform checking of $result (false or object). That's all. And also, learn about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). It will protect you against SQL injections.